# Azure Cloud Shell Stuck in Instantiation

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-shell

I have signed up for the Microsoft Sandbox. It worked fine for once but now the Cloud Shell is not opening at all in the MS Concierge Subscription. Getting the attached error. Trying to follow this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/run-docker-with-azure-container-instances/2-run-aci

If I go into the subscription, I get this - `Something went wrong...
The client with application Id '604c1504-c6a3-4080-81aa-b33091104187' is not permitted to access this API.`

Also, on the Docs page, I just keep seeing this --

```
Azure Cloud Shell

Configuring Cloud Shell for sandbox access...
```

It worked fine for the first time but after that, it hasn't been working at all.

Please do note that this subscription is not owned by me and is maintained by MS for the sandbox stuff which is part of the Microsoft Learn program. Subscription ID - `a67eb823-344a-4ddd-8346-ebe028190ccc`

Thanks,
Pranav

Comment: If the answer is helpful you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

After having a try with the link you posted, the Microsoft Sandbox works well for me. And the subscription that you have shown is not only owned you. I think it's for all the people who are here to learn. The result with the screenshots is here.

[image]

[image]

So the Microsoft Sandbox is OK. Maybe you can restart the cloud shell with the button on its left top or flush the browser. And you can also check if "Sandbox activated!" shows in the page.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old question. Just posting this for anyone stuck in an exercise.

I had the same problem. But the portal login link given in the exercise worked which was enough to complete the exercise.